# excel; conditional formatting; icon sets

Tags: microsoft-excel, icons

I have used Icon Sets of Conditional Formatting for this range based on the criteria shown on below picture,

but why 6 is amber while it's 60% and the criterion states >= 60% which should be green, doesn't the 6 equal 60%? (Max=10   and   Min=1, 6/10=60%)

similarly, while the critera says less than 40 to be red but 40 which is not less than 40 but is red (less than red should be red)

and i know Excel calculates it using Min+60%*(max-min) but i don't understand it, yet i assumed it calculates 60% times the total sum of all the data, is it true?

so it means >= percent of what?

or it's used only for percent values not simple values, or the calculation is based on another method!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT797.png)

Answer (score 2):

The formula is actually:

```
(value - MIN())/(MAX() - MIN())
```

For 6 in your given range is:

```
(6-1)/(10-1)
```

which equals `55.56%` which is lower than 60%`

[image]

Comment: but this 60% means 60% of what?